# Cannot run git clone command on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, git

I'm trying to make git clone work with Mac OS X Mountain Lion, the git installed fine but doing git clone does not and just throws:

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: ___strlcpy_chk
  Referenced from: /usr/local/git/bin/git
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

dyld: Symbol not found: ___strlcpy_chk
  Referenced from: /usr/local/git/bin/git
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

I've tried the SO answers with having a `.bash_profile` and restarting the machine, but none worked.

Comment: how did you install git? Try using homebrew.

Comment: it seems homebrew needs git at the first place, so I can't install homebrew on mac os x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Re)install XCode and the Command Line Tools: http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/mountain-lion-git-fix/